# POST max length or JS object max length?

Tags: javascript, php, google-app-engine, post

I am stuck with an annoying problem. I have an application on Google App Engine which sends some data (formatted as JSON string) from JS through POST to a php page. But when I select more than a specific amount of data, simply nothing is returned. I already tried to increase post_max_size to 20M, but not better. So where could be a limitation here? Is there another possibility to get data from JS to PHP? I tried like this:

```
function openWindowWithPost(url, name, keys, values) {
var newWindow = window.open(url, name);

if (!newWindow)
    return false;

var html = "";
html += "<html><head></head><body><form id='formid' method='post' action='"
        + url + "'>";

if (keys && values && (keys.length == values.length))
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
        html += "<input type='hidden' name='" + keys[i] + "' value='"
                + values[i] + "'/>";

html += "</form><script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById(\"formid\").submit()</sc"
        + "ript></body></html>";

newWindow.document.write(html);
return newWindow;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly check the server configuration file `php.ini` and check for the maximum post size `max_post_size`. If the default post string length isn't enough, you could increase it's length.

Answer (score 1):

If you POST those big files, maybe you should check your `upload_max_filesize`-setting too.

Another possibility: Is your big JSON-File valid? You might try this here:
http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1):

You're likely hitting the [32 MB limit per request](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Requests). To get around that, you'll need to [Upload to GCS](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload) instead.